What is a "zero term" of a polynomial?
On the Wikipedia page for homogeneous polynomials, it is stated that "a homogeneous polynomial [...] is a polynomial whose nonzero terms all have the same degree."
What is a "zero term" ? Is it a term of degree $0$ ?
The other possibility that comes to mind is that it might be a term whose coefficient is $0$ , which would be a bit strange since then I wouldn't consider it to be considered a term at all, though maybe for certain reasons it is.
If the former interpretation is correct, then apparently $4x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 + 5$ is a homogeneous polynomial whereas if the latter interpretation is correct then that isn't a homogeneous polynomial.

I think what it has in mind is that if, for instance, you add $ax$ to $x^2+y^2$ then the result is not homogeneous unless $a=0$. That may seem redundant but perhaps it makes more sense if you think of a polynomial as an infinite set of coefficients (with only finitely-many nonzero).

"non-zero" actually makes no sense in this context , and the polynomial you mentioned is not homogeneous , for this all terms must have the same degree.

The point of "non-zero" is that a polynomial (say in variables $x$ and $y$) might be written in a form like $$\sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^n a_{ij} x^i y^j$$  From that point of view, there are "terms" $a_{ij} x^i y^j$ for all $i$ and $j$, it's just that for your homogeneous polynomial the terms that don't have the right $i+j$ have coefficient $0$.  That's all it's saying.

Definition in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousPolynomial.html is more simple.

a homogeneous polynomial is a polynomial $f(x_0,\dots,x_n)$ that satifies that $f(lx_0,\dots,lx_n)=l^{\operatorname{deg}(f)}f(x_0,\dots,x_n)$ for any non-zero $l\in k$. Then, it is not difficult to show that $f$ does not admit a constant term. And the homogeneous polynomials are characterized as the polynomials such that any term have the same degree.

(1) Definition is unnecessarily introducing "Zero term" , might be it wants to cover cases like $$P(x,y)=[ax^2+bxy+cy^2]+dx+ey+f$$ which is homogeneous if & only if $d=e=f=0$ , to leave the Bracketed term.
Hence the wiki article is claiming that the "Non-Zero terms" have same Degree.
Alternately , we can say that $$P(x,y)=\sum c_ix^{a_i}y^{b_i}$$ is homogeneous of Degree $D$ if & only if $a_i+b_i=D$ , without worrying about "Zero term / Non-Zero term" here.
(2) The "real" test for checking whether $P(x,y)$ is homogeneous of Degree $D$ is :
$$P(\lambda x,\lambda y) \equiv \lambda^D P(x,y)$$
which will disallow the OP Example which has "Constant" $5$ , making it fail the test.
We do not have to worry about "Zero term / Non-Zero term" here too.
(3) We can also test $P(x,y)$ for homogeneity via :
$$P(x,y) \equiv x^D P(1,y/x)$$
$$P(x,y) \equiv y^D P(x/y,1)$$
which will ensure that all terms have same Degree $D$ , while excluding the other terms which do not match.
